# Magento 2 admin panel inaccessible after modyfying admin base URL

Tags: magento2, admin, redirection

After installing Magento 2 on my web hosting account, I changed the admin base URL, and from then, I couldn't access the admin panel any longer. Web browsers state improper redirection that goes into endless loops.

Sometimes I can login to the admin, but cannot proceed further. Then I get stopped here: `https://www.example.com/admin/admin/admin/dashboard/index/key/346c5e0399f97b43019e7fda6caa5e4a63e3920b17cda68fba711755c484cfd0/`

I ran into the issue while customizing the Magento 2 admin URL and no longer has access to the admin panel. Trying to open the admin page results to "improper redirection" that goes into endless loops. And the URL becomes `http://www.example.com/admin/admin/admin/index/index/key/blablabla`. I can only get to the admin login page displayed in raw HTML with no formatting. But I can't gain access after typing in the correct login details.

The mistake I made was this:

"Use Custom Admin URL: Yes"

"Use Custom Admin Path: No"

"Custom Admin Path: admin"

I can surely edit PHP files on the server and database tables in phpMyAdmin, if given clear step-by-step instructions.

Below is a screenshot of my "mgct_core_config_data" table regarding admin URL:
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to have the admin URL like this: http://www.example.com/admin/ and not the default URL. From lots of resources I saw online, I have a hunch that the issue lies with this table: mgct_core_config_data. Any insight?

Comment: @Priyank, Thanks for your interest. Please, see the edited post for update.

Answer (score 1):

I see you edited the store's `web/secure/base_url` and `web/unsecure/base_url` in your database which supposed to be your store's front url not admin url. So, revert these changes back.

And also revert changes back for `admin/url/custom` path.

All you need is to edit your `app/etc/env.php` and at the top of this file change your admin front name.

```
 'backend' => 
  array (
    'frontName' => 'admin',
  ),
```

And then flush cache by running `php bin/magento cache:flush`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Yes, I edited web/secure/base_url and gave it a value of https://www.example.com/ and web/unsecure/base_url and gave it a value of http://www.example.com/. What changes exactly do I have to enter for admin/url/custom? I mean the default value to revert back to? The app/etc/env.php still has the code you posted:
'backend' => 

 array (

    'frontName' => 'admin',

  ),

Comment: You wouldn't need to enter any value in `admin/url/custom`. 

I believe, you changed admin configuration in 
Admin > Stores > Configurations > Advanced > Admin > Admin Base Url 
> Use Custom Admin Url and 
> Use Custom Admin Path

If so, set those two configurations to `No`. You might then consider to delete `admin/url/custom` row from db, if the path still shows old value.

And then flush the cache.

Comment: thanks. I'm now able to gain access again to my admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your help. You've been both nice.

I've finally managed to log into my admin panel. I found the following info on Stack Overflow very direct to the issue I was facing: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202950/magento-admin-url-not-working-404-after-changing-it-cant-go-back`